# get JSON property's value when path passed as string: property1.property2.property3

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, parsing

Supposing I have a JSON object

```
let dictionary = require('../../es.json');
let obj = JSON.parse(dictionary);
```

and I have a string variable

```
let jsonPropertyPath = 'property1.property2.property3'
```

Now, I would like to get the value of the property `property1.property2.property3` of an object `obj`. Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

```
export const FindTranslation = (jsonPropertyPath: string): string => {
    let dictionary = require('../locale/' + testContext.locale + '.json') as JSON;
    return eval('dictionary.' + jsonPropertyPath);
};
```

Comment: Don't `eval`. `jsonPropertyPath.split('.').reduce((o, p) => o[p], dictionary)` does just fine and is safe.